# Nsight Eclipse : .cuda-gdbinit: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda, eclipse-cdt, nsight

I'm using Cuda 5.0 with two gpu cards on Ubuntu 11.10 with Nsight Eclipse.
When I try to debug a a program from in Eclipse I get

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
source .cuda-gdbinit
Error message from debugger back end:
.cuda-gdbinit: No such file or directory.
.cuda-gdbinit: No such file or directory.
```

I looked into Eclipse debug configuration, and I have

```
GDB debugger: cuda-gdb
GDB command file: .cuda-gdbinit
```

No where on my system is the file `.cuda-gdbinit`.
Should I create it? If so, where and with which content?
Is there something wrong with my `cuda-gdb` setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is harmless. What Nsight does is explicitly instructs cuda-gdb to read .cuda-gdbinit when starting debug session to pick up any custom settings user might have. It is perfectly fine not to have that file.

Comment: In my case, it worked after I delete the entry in the `GDB command file`, that is setting `GDB command file` to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Eclipse CDT / nsight from tying to load .cuda-gdbint (which you can safely do as other answers suggest), you must remove it from the "GDB command file" associated with your run/debug configuration.

To do that,

1. Using the menus, go to **Run | Debug Configurations**
2. Select the Run/Debug/etc configuration for which you're getting the error message
3. In the multi-tabbed section, select the **Debugger** tab
4. In the sub-multi-tabbed section, select **Main**
5. You should now see a **GDB Command File** text box. Clear it.